# Creating an orphan process

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, process

Using Ubuntu, can I create an orphan process by killing the parent process of a background process of `sleep 1000` command? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Generally - yes. But killing parent process in your case, means to kill shell process and terminate session, it is also causes linux to send SIGHUP signal to all child process and close them.
So you can run your command with nohup first
`nohup sleep 1000 &`
now you can kill parent shell with kill
The better way is just use `disown` for your background process instead of kill

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** create an orphan process because any orphaned process is immediately adopted by the process with pid == 1 (`init`) -- or by a "subreaper" process, if on Linux.

If that's what you want, you can do it (without killing anybody) by starting it as an asynchronous/background process from a subshell, with `(cmd ... &)`.

Example:

```
$ (sleep 9999 &)
$ pgrep -fa 'sleep 9999'
5435 sleep 9999
$ ps -o pid,ppid,cmd 5435
  PID  PPID CMD
 5435     1 sleep 9999
```

NB: the claim (from the other answer) that Linux will send a `SIGHUP` to all processes when the session (i.e. the session leader) is terminated is false. Both Linux and bash will only send a `SIGHUP` signal to a select subset of processes, a set that the `sleep` from the example above is not part of.

Comment: Technically in Linux the orphan process is *exactly* a process adopted by another process because the original parent has died. Your "cannot" is thus wrong.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski And why would it be so? If a process has a parent, it's not orphan. You cannot tell apart a process which was adopted from one that it was forked by its parent. The kernel keeps no history of it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you're probably confused by the concept of "orphaned process **group**" (job) as used in the context of the job control interface. An orphaned process group is a process group where no process has a parent that is part of the same **session** but not part of the same **group** as itself. That of course has nothing to do with your "an orphan process is a process adopted by another process": a process can be just that, and not be part of an orphan process group, and can be part of an orphan process group while its "true" parent it was forked from is still alive.

Comment: @lifeisdemanding By definition. Every definition of the (Unix/Linux's) orphan process I encountered states exactly this. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process): "Even though technically the process has the `init` process as its parent, it is still called an orphan process since the process that originally created it no longer exists"; [Webster](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/orphan%20process), other sources. It's possible they are all wrong, I will gladly read more official documentation. I note POSIX defines "orphaned process group" but not "orphan process".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Why, I'll fix that wiki page if I get time ;-) There's no POSIX or other standard definition of "orphan process". It used to be obvious when a process was double-forked (*of course* init didn't exec xterm), and people got used to think that there was something deeper to it. There isn't. And the use of sub-reaper processes (which is perfectly standard-compliant) makes that crystal-clear.